# How to get access permissions when installing an app instead of requesting permission while using it

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, permissions, geolocation

I'm using Cordova 5.2.0 to build my app for iOS, and then testing it on an iPhone plugged in to the computer. When getting the user's location or trying to access the camera, a notification pops up requesting permission similar to the behavior exhibited by browsers. I'd rather the user be required to allow these to install the app rather than have a popup within the app which, if rejected, will render a good bit of things useless.

From reading the docs and various other posts, I tried adding the following code to config.xml:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<!-- etc for camera and other features -->
```

In case it would help, I removed the iOS platform and re-added it. I built the project and tested it on my device, and it is still requesting those permissions within the app. How do I get permissions on installation instead?

[image: notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS's permissions model is different than Android. On Android, you are requested to give the app the necessary permissions on the install phase (that, by the way, is also changing on M version of Android OS, coming out soon). On iOS, the user can install the app, regardless of the requested permissions, and then, he/she is displayed with popups requesting them to approve give each of the necessary permissions. The user can say 'no' to any and all requested permissions and still be able to use the app ( of course, not all of is features, if he/she hasn't gave the necessary permissions). There is no way to change that, and I believe it's much better for the user. I guess Google believes it to, otherwise they wouldn't have changed their permissions model to match the one Apple has on iOS.

You can read this article to see one view about a comparison between the two models: [Android vs. iOS permissions model](http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/mobile-apps/325518-android-permission-model-sucks-compared-to-apple-ios)

What you can do, by the way, is determine when the popup will be displayed to the user. The recommended way to go is to show it to him/her only when the user first attempts to use the feature that requires the permissions. But, if you want to display the popup earlier (highly un recommended), you can simply try to "use" the ability which requires the permissions in the background, and the popup will be displayed to the user.

One last note, please notice that the user can, at any time, revoke one of more of the permissions he/she has already granted your app and your app must be able to handle that.

I hope this helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Hmm, presently, this makes my app experience TERRIBLE.  If you deny the permissions, which may happen by accident, important bits are broken forever. Can I make it ask them again each time until they accept?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you can check whether or not the permission is granted or denied and if it's denied, display an error message and send your users directly to the settings app to grant the app the necessary permissions.